# Concatenate strings literal in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *a = "3";
    char *b = "2";
    strcat(a, b);
    printf("%s\n", a);
return 0;
}
```

Running this code, gives seg fault. I tried strcpy(a,b) but it also gives the same error.

Is there any way that I can change a = "3" to a = "32" ?

Comment: so do you think they hold a space in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two variables

```
char *a = "3";
char *b = "2";
```

point to string literals and you cannot modify string literals, that yields
undefined behaviour. In most cases string literals are stored in read-only
memory, so modifying them usually ends with a segfault.

If you want to concatenate strings, then you need space for the second string.

First solution: Create bigger arrays:

```
char a[20] = "3";
char b[20] = "2";

strcat(a, b);
puts(a);
```

This would print `32`.

The problem with this solution is that if `b` is too long, then it won't fit
into `a` and you will overflow `a`. If you for example are reading from the
user, the user might enter a string that is longer than `a` can hold. In that
case `strncat` should be used or take a look at my second solution.

Second solution: dynamically allocate memory

```
int main(void)
{
    const char *a = "3";
    const char *b = "2";

    char *dest = malloc(strlen(a) + 1);

    if(dest == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    strcpy(dest, a);

    char *tmp = realloc(a, strlen(a) + strlen(b) + 1);
    if(tmp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory\n");
        free(dest);
        return 1;
    }

    dest = tmp;

    strcat(dest, b);

    // printing concatenated string
    puts(dest);

    free(dest);

    return 0;
}
```

Another solution would be

```
int main(void)
{
    const char *a = "3";
    const char *b = "2";

    size_t len = strlen(a) + strlen(b);

    // using calloc instead of malloc, because
    // calloc sets the allocated memory to 0,
    // great initialization for when using strcat
    char *dest = calloc(len + 1, 1);

    if(dest == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    strcat(dest, a);
    strcat(dest, b);

    // printing concatenated string
    puts(dest);

    free(dest);

    return 0;
}
```

Or you could also use `snprintf` like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    const char *a = "3";
    const char *b = "2";

    int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s%s", a, b);

    char *dest = malloc(len + 1);

    if(dest == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    sprintf(dest, "%s%s", a, b);

    // printing concatenated string
    puts(dest);

    free(dest);

    return 0;
}
```

This solution uses the fact that when you pass `NULL` and 0 as the first
parameters of `snprintf`, this function will return the number of characters that the
resulting string would need, thus you can use that function to determine the
total length of the concatenated string. This solution is great when you want to
concatenate different types, like for example concatenating strings with numbers.

In general there are many ways to concatenate strings, which one you take
depends on your needs: how you read the data, what you want to do with the
concatenation, whether you are using string literals, etc.

Comment: Suggesting `strncat()` is leaping out of the frying pan into the fire.  Most people don't know how to use `strncat()` correctly.  For example, `char a[32] = ""; strncat(a, z, sizeof(a));` is wrong in general — especially if the string `z` points at is (can be) longer than 31 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting segmentation fault because `a` is a pointer pointing to a string literal `"3"`, which may be stored in read-only storage, and not pointing to a valid memory location which can hold concatenated string. When doing concatenation, you need to ensure that the destination buffer should be large enough to contain the concatenated resulting string.
You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *a = "3";
    char *b = "2";
    char *buf;

    buf = malloc (strlen(a) + strlen(b) + 1);  // + 1 is to accommodate null terminating character
    if (buf == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    sprintf (buf, "%s%s", a, b);
    printf ("%s\n", buf);

    free (buf);
    return 0;
}
```